# What does it mean for a set to be open inside another set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am taking an undergraduate analysis course, and last week we began to deal with connectedness. Before defining connectnedness, our instructor gave us an alterative definition of an open set. This is the definition:

Let ${U\subset S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n}$. ${U}$ is open in ${S}$ if ${U = S\cap V}$, for some ${V}$ open in ${\mathbb{R}^n}$.

I don't understand for what it means for the set ${U}$ to be open in ${S}$, as opposed to it being open in ${\mathbb{R}^n}$. I'm trying to correlate this with the definition of an open set as given in Mathematical Analysis by Apostol, which is that a set ${A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n}$ is open if ${\forall}$ ${x \in A}$, ${\exists}$ ${\epsilon > 0}$ ${|}$ ${B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq A}$.

Does it even make sense to correlate the two? Or is openness inside a set different from openness in general, and this new definition should be accepted as gospel?

Comment: This means a topology of a set can induce it's topology to a subset of it.

Comment: We need this definition in a setting like the following. Consider the unit circle $S$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. The circle looks like something we would like to call connected, doesn't it? OTOH if $S$ were the union of two disjoint circles, say both centered at the origin but one with radius $1$ the other with radius $2$, then we would not want that union to be connected.

Comment: (cont'd) So we need a way of writing the union of two disjoint circles as a union of two relatively open sets (relatively open = open as a subset of $S$). Those two sets could be the intersection of $S$ with the open disk of radius $3/2$, and the intersection of $S$ with the open complement of the closed disk of radius $3/2$. So this definition gives us exactly what we need. Also observe that we can now call an open arc (endpoints excluded!)  of the unit circle an open subset of the unit circle even though that arc is certainly not open as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The extra baggage we get is that when we discuss openness of a set we must lug around phrases like *open as a subset of $S$*. You can do quite a bit of multivariable calculus without this extra baggage. For example, we can discuss continuity of a function defined only on the unit circle using the metric alone. But it amounts to the same, and in a more general setting we want to discuss continuity using (relative) open sets.

Answer (score 1):

The general problem is this: You have a set $X$ (in your case, $\mathbb R^n$), and you've defined a topology on that set, which essentially means, you've defined what it means for a set to be open in $X$ ($\mathbb R^n$). Note that a topology is always defined over some specific set (one of the rules is, the set itself is always open).

Now consider a subset $S$. You want to do topology on that subset, so you need to say what are the open sets on this subset.

Now, the obvious idea would be that a set is open in $S$ iff it is open in $X$. Unfortunately, this only works if $S$ happens to be open in $X$, but you want to do topology also on other subsets. For example, you might consider a straight line (a copy of $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R^n$; indeed, in that case you want the topology to be exactly the usual topology of $\mathbb R$, so all the results on $\mathbb R$ that you know are still valid.

But if just taking the open sets as is doesn't always work, what can we do then?

Well, if the open sets don't fit, we just make them to fit. What we do is to just cut away those parts of the open sets $V$ in $X$ ($\mathbb R^n$) that are outside $S$ (that's exactly what $S \cap V$ does), and declare the resulting sets the open sets of $S$. And it turns out that this works perfecly:

- It always gives a valid topology, no matter which subset $S$ we consider.
- Open sets in $X$ that already happen to be subsets of $S$ are still open as subsets of $S$.
- If $S$ happens to be open in $X$, we get the very same result as the first idea.
- If $X$ is a metric space (like $\mathbb R^n$) with the topology defined by its metric, then you get the same topology this way as you get when you first restrict the metric to $S$ (making $S$ a metric space in its own right), and then use that metric to define the topology of $S$. Note that this includes, but is not limited to, the example of straight lines in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an "alternative" definition of open set. It's the definition of the so-called *subspace topology*. It is the best way to define a topology (i.e. which sets are considered open) on $S$ which agrees with the topology of $\Bbb R^n$.

For instance, in $S=[0,1]\subseteq \Bbb R$ (where $\Bbb R$ has the standard topology), we have that $[0,\frac12)$ is considered open, because you can write it as the intersection between $S$ and some open interval, like $(-1,\frac12)$. Of course, something like $(\frac13,\frac23)$ is also open in $S$.

And yes, it makes some sense to correlate the two. A subset $U\subseteq S$ is open iff for any $s\in S$ there is an $\epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon(s)\cap S\subseteq U$. Or you could consider $S$ as a metric space in its own right (with the metric inherited from $\Bbb R^n$), and in that case you can actually remove the "${}\cap S$" from the above (because the interpretation of $B$ changes), and it will truly look exactly the way your used to.

Comment: So is that the way open sets are defined? As members of a set with an associated topology? (I don't know any topology, just know a few definitions that I looked up while trying to understand the analysis lectures).

Comment: A topology is the collection of all open subsets of a set. In topology that's the _definition_ of an open set. A topological space is a set together with a topology on that set.